# What was a general called in ancient Egypt?

Tags: ancient, egyptian

What was a general called in ancient Egypt?

website in the web used only term "general", "commander of nubian units" or other similar. Nobody used a name of commander rank in ancient egypt. Is it affect we haven't find how they called `general` because all glory go to pharonh ? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Faulkner](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3855309) uses the word "general" to translate *jmj-r mšꜥ* (later *jmy-r mšꜥ*), literally "overseer of soldiers". This title is common from the Old Kingdom onwards, and can also mean "foreman" in civil engineering contexts (since the army was often involved in major engineering projects).

In the Middle Kingdom, there's a higher title *jmy-r mšꜥ wr* "great overseer of soldiers" ("generalissimo", "commander in chief", etc), and in the Eleventh Dynasty *jmy-r mšꜥ šmꜥw mḥw* "general of Upper and Lower Egypt" (possibly a sort of war minister), but neither of these actually seems to have commanded troops in the field. There were also various lower titles, like *jdnw* "lieutenant", who reported to a *jmy-r mšꜥ*.

Comment: thank you ! exist a hyphothesis how we should say thats word ? (for example -  jmj-r mšꜥ )

Comment: @HamilkarBarkas The "Egyptological pronunciation", which isn't at all how the ancient Egyptians actually spoke and just makes it easier for English-speaking linguists to talk about the words, would be _imi-er mesha_. The actual reconstructed pronunciation can probably be figured out, since it's a pretty standard construction, but I don't know it.